# Predicting 100 values of function f(x) using LSTM

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn, lstm

I am trying to predict 100 values of the function f(x) in the future. I found a script online where it was predicting the price of a stock into the future and decided to modify it for the purpose of my research. Unfortunately, the prediction is quite a bit off. Here is the script:

```
#import packages
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, LSTM
import tensorflow as tf

#for normalizing data
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))

#read the file
df = pd.read_csv('MyDataSet')

#print the head
df.head()

look_back = 60
num_periods = 20
NUM_NEURONS_FirstLayer = 128
NUM_NEURONS_SecondLayer = 64
EPOCHS = 1
num_prediction = 100
training_size = 8000 #initial

#creating dataframe
data = df.sort_index(ascending=True, axis=0)
new_data = pd.DataFrame(index=range(0,len(df)),columns=['XValue', 'YValue'])

for i in range(0,len(data)):
   new_data['XValue'][i] = data['XValue'][i]
   new_data['YValue'][i] = data['YValue'][i]

#setting index
new_data.index = new_data.XValue

new_data.drop('XValue', axis=1, inplace=True)

#creating train and test sets
dataset = new_data.values

train = dataset[0:training_size,:]
valid = dataset[training_size:,:]

scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
scaled_data = scaler.fit_transform(dataset)

x_train, y_train = [], []
for i in range(look_back,len(train)):
    x_train.append(scaled_data[i-look_back:i,0])
    y_train.append(scaled_data[i,0])
x_train, y_train = np.array(x_train), np.array(y_train)

x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (x_train.shape[0],x_train.shape[1],1))

#Custom Loss Function
def my_loss_fn(y_true, y_pred):
    squared_difference = tf.square(y_true - y_pred)
    return tf.reduce_mean(squared_difference, axis=-1)

#Training Phase
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(NUM_NEURONS_FirstLayer,input_shape=(look_back,1), 
return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(NUM_NEURONS_SecondLayer,input_shape=(NUM_NEURONS_FirstLayer,1)))

model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss=my_loss_fn, optimizer='adam')

model.fit(x_train,y_train,epochs=EPOCHS,batch_size=2, verbose=2)

inputs = dataset[(len(dataset) - len(valid) - look_back):]
inputs = inputs.reshape(-1,1)
inputs  = scaler.transform(inputs)
X_test = []
for i in range(look_back,inputs.shape[0]):
    X_test.append(inputs[i-look_back:i,0])
X_test = np.array(X_test)

#Validation Phase
X_test = np.reshape(X_test, (X_test.shape[0],X_test.shape[1],1))
PredictValue = model.predict(X_test)
PredictValue = scaler.inverse_transform(PredictValue)

#Measures the RMSD between the validation data and the predicted data
rms=np.sqrt(np.mean(np.power((valid-PredictValue ),2)))

train = new_data[:int(new_data.index[training_size])]
valid = new_data[int(new_data.index[training_size]):]

valid['Predictions'] = PredictValue 

valid = np.asarray(valid).astype('float32')

valid = valid.reshape(-1,1)

#Prediction Phase
def predict(num_prediction, model):
    prediction_list = valid[-look_back:]

    for _ in range(num_prediction):
        x = prediction_list[-look_back:]
        x = x.reshape((1, look_back, 1))
        out = model.predict(x)[0][0]
        prediction_list = np.append(prediction_list, out)
    prediction_list = prediction_list[look_back-1:]
    
    return prediction_list

#Get the predicted x-value
def predict_x(num_prediction):
    last_x = df['XValue'].values[-1]
    XValue = range(int(last_x),int(last_x)+num_prediction+1)
    prediction_x = list(XValue)
    return prediction_x

#Predict the y-value and the x-value
forecast = predict(num_prediction, model)
forecast_x = predict_x(num_prediction)
```

The file I was using was just for the function f(x) = sin(2πx/10), where x is all natural numbers from 0 to 10,000. Following the above, I get the following plot:

[Prediction-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/caDtL.jpg)

Granted I am using only epochs of 1 and I am busy running a new job with a value of 50, but I was hoping for something a lot better. Any advice to improve the prediction here?

I also decided to modify the script and only predict one value at a time, add it to the dataset and then re-run the script. 100 times. It takes long and it obviously has its own issues (such as using the predicted value of the previous x (step)), but it's the best solution I can think of now. This is the plot I got for it. I can attach this file if you want, but it's not the one I want to continue focusing on with this project:

[Prediction-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkLoH.jpg)

Any sort of help would be appreciated in getting a better prediction.

Much appreciated